# Galaxy Nexus screen flashes and brightness issues on various button taps and screens

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, screen

While using my Galaxy Nexus at night in the dark, I started experiencing issues where the screen would flash for a moment to what felt like full brightness when I tap on certain buttons. It seems inconsistent, but frequent. I've had it happen when pressing the back button in various apps, or switching to different apps in the application switcher. It's bright enough to say that it kind of hurts my eyes.

It also seems like certain screens get locked into full brightness. One example is the main timeline screen of the official Twitter app.

I have Automatic Brightness turned off, and the brightness slider at the lowest setting.

Any ideas as to what causes this? Is there some setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this happen to me. Seeing your answer, Moskie, I carefully removed the apps one at a time from the application switcher by sliding them to the right, testing between each one. For me, pressing home from the web browser caused my screen to do a slow flaah, opening the apps menu made it go bright and stay bright.

The app that caused the trouble? Camera.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up closing all running apps using the application switcher. That seemed to do the trick. I'm not sure which one was causing the problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called [Screen filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5oYXhvciJd), which I use to use my mobile during night.  Even when the brightness is at its lowest value, the screen is still bright enough during night to disturb others and hurt my own eyes when reading for long time.  This app enables me to reduce the brightness even further the lowest limit.  Though this does not neither help you to automatically adjust the brightness nor solve the random sudden increase of brightness. But still I posted this as it might help you or others if the lowest brightness is still not low enough.

Answer (score -1):

Strange, i have never heard of something like that, it must be an app which are causing it... Anything you have installed recently? I would try and remove some of the recent installed apps, and see if that works, or make a reset of the phone.. If it still happens after a reset, then it's a hardware issue, and you should talk with those who sold it to you...